# DelayedJob ERROR: there is already one or more instance(s) of the program running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, delayed-job, web-worker

Some backstory:

My server ran out of disk space last night while delayed_job workers were running off jobs processing images.

When I try to stop the workers, I get the response "Terminated".

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop
Terminated
```

Then I run the following to see that the workers were terminated.

```
ps -ef | grep delayed_job
servername      4474  4274  0 02:37 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto delayed_job
```

Now I try to start up new workers.

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n2 start
ERROR: there is already one or more instance(s) of the program running
ERROR: there is already one or more instance(s) of the program running
```

This is the error that I'm getting, I'm not able to start any new workers even though it seems that I have stopped all active workers.

This was confusing me so I ran

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job status
delayed_job: running [pid 0]
delayed_job: running [pid 0]
```

This seems wrong [pid 0], it seems like my workers have been corrupted and I'm hoping to figure out how to solve this issue. Thanks!

I'm running on Linux Ubuntu LTS 10.4.

EDIT: So I deleted the 2 worker files I found in tmp/pids which allowed me to start and stop workers. However, the workers will not run anything because I believe I need to have PID files generated in the tmp folder.

Comment: So I deleted my 2 worker files in tmp/pids/ which allowed me to create workers, however, i believe I need to generate some pid files before it will run jobs.

Answer (score 7):

I ran this command to solve the issue:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 --pid-dir=tmp/pids restart
```

By specifying the directory it was able to fix the issue of lack of PID file.

Answer (score 2):

Put in some random pid (which is not a pid of an existing process) on that file, and then try to start your daemon. You will see a message similar to:

`pid-file for killed process 32323123 found (/path/to/pid/file), deleting.`

and your daemon will get started.